# Combining Javascript files using a Javascript preprocessor?

Tags: javascript

I recently started using SASS (a preprocessor for CSS) and I'm really liking it. My favorite feature is being able to split my stylesheets into separate files so everything is more organized.

I'm wondering if there's something like SASS for Javascript. My Javascript files are getting huge and I'm spending a lot of time just trying to find stuff. I want to be able to split my file into smaller files and have them automatically combined to serve to the clients. How would I do this?

Comment: http://browserify.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely GruntJS http://gruntjs.com/.

What you are to embark on here is a journey into real professional web development and quite frankly front-end engineering :) There will be no turning back.

Essentially you create a Gruntfile.js with common tasks like file concatenation and perhaps minify/uglifying your final javascript. You could even have the grunt tasks handle your SASS as well. There is a plethora of Grunt tasks you'll find useful in your professional workflow.

In order to use Grunt you'll need to install Node http://nodejs.org/; in particular its package manager `npm` https://www.npmjs.org/ to use Grunt but that's super simple to setup with something like homebrew http://brew.sh/.

I know all this can seem a bit daunting at first, but trust me it all comes together quite seamlessly once you get the hang of it.

Take your time, all the sites referenced do a good job in explaining how to use them and what's required to get started.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

check the following handy tools for JS pre-processing:

[jsmake-preprocessor](https://code.google.com/p/jsmake-preprocessor/)

[JavaScript Preprocessor](http://js-preprocessor.com/)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into browserify and grunt or gulp.

Browserify is great for modularizing your javascript code in separate files, and grunt/gulp watch your files for changes and automatically bundle them into one production JS file for you. (You can also set them up to watch/compile your SCSS files, compile coffeescript to JS, etc.).

Browserify:
http://browserify.org/
Quick intro: http://blakeembrey.com/articles/introduction-to-browserify/

Grunt:
http://gruntjs.com/

Gulp:
http://gulpjs.com/

A bit of a learning curve to get up and running, but worth it for the gains in productivity. Take a look at grunt and gulp and see which one seems more intuitive for you, as you only need one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Grunt as well.  There are a ton of plugins and it can perform virtually any task you can script.  It's a valuable tool in your toolkit, so I recommend learning it. I've recommended this screencast others in the past who struggled to get started with Grunt and they all agreed that it was helpful.  Maybe it will be for you too: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/130-first-moments-grunt/

That said, in practice I actually use CodeKit.  I just find it to be a faster workflow for me to compile, lint and compress my files for production.  It is very versatile and will take care of, among others, your SASS and your JS files.  The UI is intuitive and easy to configure for new projects, and I like the added feature of being able to see my changes in real-time without having to manually refresh my browser(s).  If you use a Mac, and you're willing to shell out $29, download the free trial and check it out.  https://incident57.com/codekit/